# AngularJs: How to add a custom filter inside an ngRepeat to manipulate decimals?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a single object of multiple property names and values that are being printed out via ng-repeat. Two of the objects inside this large object, are called currencyName and currencyPrice.

By default, these objects have 8 decimals hardcoded into them in the backend, and my task is to manipulate certain currencyName to show 5 decimals, or 8 decimals in the display page with Angular. By default, the currencyPrices have 8 decimals hardcoded into them on the backend, which cannot be touched since that bit of code is reused in other places. For the display page I'm working on, we use the filter | number:2 by default.

I tried to create a custom filter that will target the array of the main object, run a for loop/forEach method, target the currencyName object, and if it matches an array that contains currencyNames to be manipulated, the angular display page will show 5 decimals (in this case).

This has proven very difficult to me. I don't have the full code to paste it here, but here's some sample code to show what the code looks.

```
<tr ng-repeat="full in fulls.mainList" class="animate-repeat">
  <td>{{full.currencyName}}</td>
  <td>{{full.tradedAverage | number:2}}</td>
  <td>{{full.tradedAmount | number:2}}</td>
  <td>{{full.currencyPrice | number:2}}</td>
</tr>
```

fulls in this case is the large object that's being parsed inside the controller.

Comment: 1) whats is </i> in your HTML? - it's wrong. 2) can you present the js code of the filter as well?

Comment: Use a real MVVM framework instead of angular….

Comment: @shershen Hey, sorry I removed it. there were several other tags besides the <i> tag  that helped with css and other bits. I stripped out all the gibberish to make it appear as clean as possible. Of note, I am able to apply custom filters listed by scotch.io from https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters, so I made sure that regular filters worked, but not the one I'm trying to build.

Comment: @Mjaaay, So, do you want to restrict the `currencyName`?

Comment: @AbhilashPA-Pullelil Hey, I'm not sure what restricting would imply. Let's say, the object currencyName have property names called CNY, USD, etc, and I created an array that contains ["GBP", "NOK"]. If currencyName matches anything insides this array, then currencyPrice of THAT currencyName will have its decimals changed from 2 to 5 - via a custom filter.

Comment: @Jurion, How helpful is your comment to his problem?

Comment: @OlatundeGaruba Well, it is.Using Angular IS the problem. That framework is just bad. I understand the poster does not have a choice (cf his comment), but still. Using Angular is literally firing with bazooka at your own code. I think it’s relevant. Angular has no respect for patterns or any thing else… Edit : note, I don't even cite other frameworks. People can find with a cheat " google"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your code and it should work:

```
   <div ng-repeat="full in fulls.mainList">
       <span>{{full.currencyName}}</span>
       <span>{{full.tradedAverage | number:2}}</span>
       <span>{{full.tradedAmount | number:2}}</span>
       <span>{{full.currencyPrice | number:2}}</span>
   </div>

    $scope.fulls = {
          mainList : [
            {
              currencyName: 'TEST',
              tradedAverage: '12.123434',
              tradedAmount: '13.133434',
              currencyPrice: '14.143434'
            }
          ]
       };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1/

Maybe you have ',' instead of '.' in your numbers?

Comment: Hey, that's working as expected. However, my problem is, if currencyName: HKD, I want currencyPrice to become | number:5. Therefore I will need to create an array that holds a list of currency names (such as HKD) to output different decimals. Right now, it is as you posted, showing 2 decimals by default

Comment: Something like this? Maybe you add an additonal property like 'decimalLength' and returning this if something matches.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2/

Comment: I like your solution. I'm just having trouble implementing it because our codebase is very unorganized and I'm trying to trace the files. Right now I'm getting undefined when I console.log the currencyName after being passed via  | number:getIndividualFormat(full.currencyName), likely  a scope issue. Thing is, the mainList actually comes from an array, and  comes from a variable who's value is $rootScope.orderBook, and since these are defined  in a complicated function, it's killing my brain to try trace them. Once I get it sorted I'll approve your answer!

Comment: I checked this as the answer, although in the end, I was told to create a custom filter so that it could be reused elsewhere. I ended up declaring several arrays inside the filter, and added some if statements using .indexOf and parseFloat to return them into angular like {{ full.price | decimalFilter:baseCurrency}}

Answer (score 0):

Note it's pretty easy to write your own function in your controller that encapsulates the logic for the number of decimals.

```
<tr ng-repeat="full in fulls.mainList" class="animate-repeat">
  <td>{{full.currencyName}}</td>
  <td>{{full.tradedAverage | number: (fnThatTellsTheNumberOfDecimals(full, 'tradedAverage')}}</td>
  <td>{{full.tradedAmount | number:(fnThatTellsTheNumberOfDecimals(full, 'tradedAmount')}}</td>
  <td>{{full.currencyPrice | number:(fnThatTellsTheNumberOfDecimals(full, 'currencyPrice')}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then in your controller, write something like:

```
$scope.fnThatTellsTheNumberOfDecimals = function(element, attr){
    if (attr === 'example' && element.type === 'some'){ return 2; }
    return 6;
};
```

Comment: That looks like an interesting approach. How do you run the fnThatTellsTheNumberOfDecimals inside {{ }}? Some googling didn't get me much results... right now console.log show what element and attr as undefined